# exctract first part of row name in a pandas dataset

Tags: python

Im trying to exctract the first part of the column 'Player' to work better. I want to clean my dataset but I dont know how I can do it.

The column name is `Player` and rows are like this: `Ismael Aaneba\Ismael-Aaneba`, I want to take the first part till .

I try it:

```
def clear_player(c):
    try:
      return c[-0:\]
    except:
      return c

dt['Player'] = dt['Player'].apply(lambda x: clear_player(x))
dt.head(2)
```

Comment: Please repeat your materials on string search and slice notation.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without a more full example, but you can use built-in series methods like so

```
dt['Player']=dt['Player'].str.split('\\').str[0]
```